# Extract Unicode data from CSV file

Tags: python, csv, unicode

I have a CSV file like this 
encoding   UTF-8

```
# id    english_word    part_of_speech  malayalam_definition
174569  .net    n   പുത്തന്‍ കമ്പ്യൂട്ടര്‍ സാങ്കേതികത ഭാഷ
116102  A bad patch n   കുഴപ്പം പിടിച്ച സമയം
115869  A bed of nails  n   പ്രയാസപ്പെടുന്ന അവസ്ഥ
200587  A bed of nails  idm ശരശയ്യ
115768  A bed of roses  n   സുഖകരമായ അവസ്ഥ
115767  A bed of roses  n   പൂമെത്ത
113832  A bed of thorn  n   അസുഖകരമായ അവസ്ഥ
113665  A bed roses n   പൂമെത്ത
```

I have to extract all  Unicode data from the file  having `n` tag

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', newline='\t', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

This is the code I have but it is not working The code is not producing output, it does not . Any suggestions ?

Python 2.7

Comment: Python 2.7? Don't you get a *TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function*?

Comment: @JanneKarila Yes I got error, But how to extract the parts after n tag

Comment: That's Python 3 usage of `open`.

Comment: @JanneKarila  how to extract the parts after n tag? I am getting know Idea

Comment: @JanneKarila TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: @JanneKarila No, the code is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [the original code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21624750/2), `" n" in row` does not match anything because there is a tab character before the `n`. If there is always a tab, try `"\tn" in row` instead.

Now, the problem is that your code is a Python 3 version. In Python 2.7, the `open` function does not take a `newline` argument, hence the `TypeError`.

This should work with a tab-delimited file:

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        if "n" in row:
            print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the csv file before you iterate in it with `for row in f`.

First, import the csv package:

```
import csv
```

After, read the csv file:

```
with open('mycsv.csv','r') as f:
  with open('n.csv','w') as new_file:
    file_read = csv.reader(f,delimiter=';')
    for row in file_read:
      if not extract_n(row):
        new_file.write(row)
```

The delimiter field can be a semicolon, comma, o whatever you have.